# How do I get a Huijia gamepad working?

Tags: configuration, joystick

I have a usb n64 controller adapter and I don't know how to calibrate it. I ran jscal and everything but the joystick portion still only registers half way. and when I do try to calibrate it, It thinks it has 12 axises!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I recently figured out how to do this myself after much searching, trial and error, etc.

I wrote a detailed tutorial which I posted on my blog.
Feel free to distribute!

http://raopinion.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/mayflash-n64-controller-adapter/
(*And if this link goes dead, try [this archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230617014932/https://raopinion.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/mayflash-n64-controller-adapter/))*.

Comment: Answering an old question is awesome man, good tutorial.